# SwiperJs with reactJS, on Next click it skips the odd slides and on click Prev it skips the even slides

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I have SwiperJs installed on my nextJS project.
Everything works perfectly, just the previous and next arrows skips slides.

Note: With left and right drag, it work fine. Just issues with NEXT and PREV arrows.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Navigation, Pagination } from "swiper";
import { Swiper } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/swiper.min.css";
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css";
import "swiper/swiper-element.css";
import "./smoke-swiper.scss";

/*
props:
- chidlren => Swiper slides
- Style => Swiper root style
*/
const SmokeSwiper = ({ children, style }) => {
  return (
    <div className='smoke-swiper_root'>
      <Swiper
        style={{ maxWidth: "600px", maxHeight: "400px", ...style }}
        spaceBetween={30}
        pagination={{
          type: "fraction", // clickable: true,dynamicBullets: true,
        }}
        navigation={true}
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination]}
        className='mySwiper'>
        <div>{children}</div>
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SmokeSwiper;
```

I am expecting the slides with work in sequence [1,2,3,4....] with Next and Prev arrow events.